How do I properly remove these two extensions from my Chrome?
I have these two extensions that remain no matter what I do. Someone has any ideas on what to do?
The two extensions are:

yglSearch
Your Search Bar



when i open the setup.exe it tells me that the directory or the file is unreadable or damaged
